# Base64 encode - decode issue

Tags: encoding, base64, decoding

I read that Base64 is deterministic algorithm, and produce unique results. Consider these two encoded base64 values:

> 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

&

> 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

These both give me same decoded output. How is this possible? I couldn't find any visible difference between decoded format of these two values.

Is it related to encoding and decoding schemes like UTF 8 and ASCII?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decoded strings are different -- they have different CR/LF sequences at the end of lines: `\n\n (0a0a)` vs `\r\n\r\n (0d0a0d0a)`:

```
00000060  20 54 65 78 74 20 43 6f  6e 74 65 6e 74 3a 20 0a  | Text Content: .|
00000070  0a 20 20 20 20 44 61 74  61 3a 20 3c 69 6e 70 75  |.    Data: <inpu|


00000060  20 54 65 78 74 20 43 6f  6e 74 65 6e 74 3a 20 0d  | Text Content: .|
00000070  0a 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 44  61 74 61 3a 20 3c 69 6e  |...    Data: <in|
```

Hint: use `hexdump -C <file>` to get such output.